# Are there any health risks with regular, long term use of anti-perspirant?

Tags: risks, toxicity, pores, antiperspirant-deodorant, skin-absorption

Is there any evidence that the chemicals used should be a cause for concern? Do any active ingredients enter the blood stream and is there any risk to damage to your pores?